# Firefox ignores padding-bottom with box-sizing:border box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firefox ignores padding-bottom  with box-sizing:border box.
I am trying to fit two child divs into container div of 300px.
child1 - height 100%;
child2 - from bottom height 100px;

child1 has border box and padding-bottom:100px which should reduce child1 height to (100% - 100px) giving way to child2.
This implementation works fine in webkit but firefox fails.
Is there work around to fix this? I don't want to use css calc().

here is the example - http://jsfiddle.net/827D6/1/

css used :

```
.container{
 height:300px;
 width:300px;   
 background-color:black;
}
.child1{
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    padding: 20px 20px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y:auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.child2{
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
    bottom:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position absolute for this easily. Just make the container `relative` and set the height of the second child with position `bottom:0`. The first child is then set to `top:0;bottom:100px;`.

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:black;
}
.child1 {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:100px;
    left:0;
    padding: 20px 20px 0;
    overflow-y:auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.child2 {
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:green;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/827D6/2/)

Comment: This also makes more sense since the scrollbar doesn't just disappears underneath child2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in my scenario have another div as a side bar which run through height of my container div and side bar div is absolute. link : jsfiddle.net/827D6/5 . Width:100% will make my divs come out of wrapper.

Comment: @user1748439 If that is also a child of the relative parent then it shouldn't matter, they can all be position absolute. Can you please explain this better? Also your jsfiddle doesn't change from the original.

Comment: @user1748439 I see the updated jsfiddle link. Can you better explain how the blue div is supposed to be place? and why my current answer doesn't work? I'd like to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.element {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
.element::before, .element::after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {  
    .element::after {
        height:10px;
    }
}
```